# How to handle a missing confirmation email for a job offer?

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, email

I recently accepted a job offer at a bank, but did not receive the confirmation email they said they sent. Should I call them now to say I did not get it, or should I wait until my first day? Either they entered my email incorrectly, or the network is slow. It has been 4 days and 2 of them have been business days.

Everyone tells me I still have the job, even without the email, but could they still take it back with out the email?

Comment: Check your spam folder and ask them to resend the e-mail. Never put off till tomorrow what can be done today. It's better to be proactive.

Comment: no need to say thanks in the question -- upvoting answers is the best way to say thanks.

Answer (score 11):

> I do not know if I should call them and tell them I did not get it, or
>   should I wait until my first day and tell them?

I always consider an offer "unofficial" until I have the paperwork in my hands. Usually, that involves snail-mail, but I suppose email could work too.

**Call them now.** Tell them that you didn't receive their email and guide them through sending it correctly. As @HorusKol correctly suggests, make sure you confirm they have the correct email address on record. It should only take a few minutes of your time and their time.

You could even offer to run over to their office and pick up the printed paperwork if that would be easier for them. I've done this myself more than once.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have called them to let them know. :)

Comment: Hardcopy. Definitely.

Comment: Make sure you confirm they have the correct email address on record.

Answer (score 3):

If you've checked all your email junk filters then just call them and ask for the confirmation email to be resent. I'm sure it's fine but it's always a good idea to have everything just in case you need to dispute something later. I don't see it being a major problem for the person to resend the email.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have called them to let them know. :)